# Word or phrase that encapsulates physical and emotional well-being?

Tags: word-choice

As in "Technology has the ability to affect us in more than just our _______/well-being it can also affect the environment around us."

*Side note : I’am also looking for a word that kinda has to do with the side of our lives that has to do with economics/job .  Like as in it can affect  _____ side of our lives, safety in job/nank account privacy type of thing. I know this is vague*.⋅

Comment: Probably you mean 'quality of life'.  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=quality+of+life+definition

Comment: That seems to to help a lot with what I am trying to say/describe but seems somewhat more general than what I am looking for (for the first question at least). That seems to help fit though with my second question. Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with just, *'well-being'* for the first part? That covers mental and physical.

Comment: That's what I was going with at first but realized well-being can cover more than just physical and emotional. It could also mean financial well-being or many other things. I was trying to encapsulate those two in a word to expand later. Also because I was going to be writing about another type of well-being to expand upon later.

Comment: Perhaps "living conditions" or "destiny".

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though *personal well-being* would work for you.

> Technology has the ability to affect us in more than just our *personal well-being*, it can also affect the environment around us.

It can mean physical well-being, emotional well-being, material well-being, etc.

Comment: That was what I was was going to use at first but I realized I wanted a word that could encapsulate the two of them to expand upon later. I was also trying to do the same with two other types of well-being so I could have the one word to expand upon like the other. "Well-being" seemed too general. But you are probably right I will just need to find a work around or reword what I am trying to say. Thanks!